# Video File Metadata information loss during file transfer

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am facing a problem during large file transfer from local drive to network mapped drive and problem is large video file meta data information like video duration,frame rate loss during file transfer.Please help to figure out.

Comment: I am using File.Copy(SourePath,DestinationPath,true) in C#;

Comment: Where does FFmpeg fit into the question?

Comment: FFmpeg command is used to generate large video from camera streaming and video meta data showing good in local drive but not network drive.

Comment: “Not showing” in what? Where doesn’t the metadata show up?